# Alternative to css flex for dynamic layout

Tags: html, css

I have a layout that need to fit into a page that i achieved in flex as follow. The entire page should be fitted into the browser view. As i need to support older browser (that does not support flex), any alternative that i can use?

I am expecting a pure CSS solution **without flexbox and javascript** to acheive similar effect.

Plunkr: [Click here](https://plnkr.co/edit/DzMnHcNSBJjZBDl6TFF1?p=preview)

```
<ion-content scroll="false" has-header="true" style="display: flex; flex-flow: column;height:100vh; ">
        <div style="background-color: red;">
          Content 1 (height based on content)
        </div>
        <div style="background-color: yellow; display:flex;flex-direction:row;height:100vh;">
          <div style="flex:1;hight:100vh;">
            content 2 part 1
          </div>
          <div style="flex:1;">
            Content 2 part 2
          </div>
        </div>
        <div>
          <img style="width: 100%;" src="http://dummyimage.com/600x400/000/fff" />
        </div>
      </ion-content>
```

[image]

Comment: You should at least show us what have you tried, rather than just dumping a request.

Comment: @Paulie_D i have tried on using `display: table-cell` and normal `div` for the alternative but i only manage to achieve the layout but unable to fit it into a full page view as it requires dynamic height calculation.

Comment: Easy solution: preserve flexbox and use a [**polyfill**](https://www.google.es/search?q=flexbox+polyfill). Hard solution: try something different by yourself and ask us if you have an specific problem.

Answer (score 2):

You can achieve this using **CSS tables**

```css
body,
html {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0
}
.w100 {
  width: 100%
}
.table {
  display: table;
  table-layout: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%
}
.cell {
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: top;
}
.yellow {
  background: yellow
}
.red {
  background: red;
}
img {
  width: 100%;
  display: block
}
```

```html
<ion-content scroll="false" has-header="true" class="table">
  <div class="red w100">
    Content 1 (height based on content)
  </div>
  <div class="yellow table">
    <div class="cell">
      content 2 part 1
    </div>
    <div class="cell">
      Content 2 part 2
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="red">
    <img src="http://dummyimage.com/600x400/000/fff" />
  </div>
</ion-content>
```

Here is your `flexbox` snippet  to compare

---

```html
<ion-content scroll="false" has-header="true" style="display: flex; flex-flow: column;height:100vh; ">
        <div style="background-color: red;">
          Content 1 (height based on content)
        </div>
        <div style="background-color: yellow; display:flex;flex-direction:row;height:100vh;">
          <div style="flex:1;hight:100vh;">
            content 2 part 1
          </div>
          <div style="flex:1;">
            Content 2 part 2
          </div>
        </div>
        <div>
          <img style="width: 100%;" src="http://dummyimage.com/600x400/000/fff" />
        </div>
      </ion-content>
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. Maybe i should clarify something more clearly. As you could see from the code that is written in flex, the entire content **fits exactly into browser viewport** and this is the challenge i am having when converting from flexbox to non-flexbox css. It seems that the solution you given does not fit exactly into browser viewport.

Comment: Sorry but it does fit

Comment: you should run the snippet in full-page or at least see it here https://jsfiddle.net/ok5t3o7s/

Comment: I have reproduce it inside plunker https://plnkr.co/edit/SUQimZzE5ZfUI9fHX8VS?p=preview and fiddler https://jsfiddle.net/174b3a1c/. It seems to me that only content 1 and content 2 fits into the viewport but the image is out from the viewport. Kindly correct me if i miiss out some steps in your solution provided.

Comment: it is something related to your ionic framweork, I'm not a user, so can't help much, I used a hack `max-height:75%`, and it seems to work [plunkr](https://plnkr.co/edit/wO7NYQWNDZrd95IC5DvI?p=preview)

Comment: Hi, I have reproduce it again in fiddle here using pure html https://jsfiddle.net/ok5t3o7s/2/ but the image is still out of viewport. Besides, there should not be a hack in the content 2 div. The height should be a calculation based on `full height - content 1 height - dynamic image height` so that the entire content 1, content 2 and image fits perfectly into viewport. I am having trouble acheive it without using flex and javascript

Comment: I have updated an image for better illustration purpose in question

Comment: Given your existent image you only can do that with `flex` , still you can use `calc()` if you know the image height,https://jsfiddle.net/09x5fydo/ .

Comment: @dippas I have a question on an alternative to flex [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75432484/html-tables-in-flex-layout-are-getting-overlapped-after-converting-to-pdf) on SO. Can you check once and answer when you have time?