# HTML tables in flex layout are getting overlapped after converting to PDF

Tags: html, css, html-table, flexbox, weasyprint

Trying to convert html file to pdf using `weasyprint`, but due to [bug](https://github.com/Kozea/WeasyPrint/issues/1805) in `weasyprint`, I can't use `flex` layout as it is overlapping the two tables in the first row. Is there any other workaround to get two tables in the first row side by side without disturbing other elements like `<p>` and two tables after that?

Instead of using flexboxes, need to use other alternative to achieve same align as mentioned in sample code!

```html
<html>

<head>
    <style>
        /* Custom CSS */
        table {
            border-collapse: collapse;
            width: 45%;
        }

        th,
        td {
            border: 1px solid black;
            padding: 8px;
        }

        th {
            background-color: #f2f2f2;
        }

        /* td:first-child {
            background-color: grey;
        } */

        .first-column {
            background-color: rgb(187, 185, 185);
        }

        .mainWrapper {
            display: flex;
            flex-direction: column;
        }

        .rowTable {
            display: flex;
            flex-direction: row;
        }


        /* End Custom CSS */
    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="mainWrapper">
        <div class="rowTable">
            <table style="margin-right: 20px;">
                <tr>
                    <td class="first-column">table 111 Header 1</td>
                    <td>Header 2</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td class="first-column">Row 1, Cell 1</td>
                    <td>Row 1, Cell 2</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td class="first-column">Row 2, Cell 1</td>
                    <td>Row 2, Cell 2</td>
                </tr>
            </table>
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <td class="first-column">table 222 Header 1</td>
                    <td>Header 2</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td class="first-column">Row 1, Cell 1</td>
                    <td>Row 1, Cell 2</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td class="first-column">Row 2, Cell 1</td>
                    <td>Row 2, Cell 2</td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </div>
        <div>
            <p> some paragraph </p>
            <div>
                <div>
                    <table style="margin-bottom:20px;">
                        <tr>
                            <th>table 333 Header 1</th>
                            <th>Header 2</th>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>Row 1, Cell 1</td>
                            <td>Row 1, Cell 2</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>Row 2, Cell 1</td>
                            <td>Row 2, Cell 2</td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                    <table>
                        <tr>
                            <th>table 444 Header 1</th>
                            <th>Header 2</th>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>Row 1, Cell 1</td>
                            <td>Row 1, Cell 2</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>Row 2, Cell 1</td>
                            <td>Row 2, Cell 2</td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                </div>

            </div>
</body>

</html>
```

**Actual output:**( in pdf)

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `display: inline-table;` on the tables (*without* `display:flex` on their parent element). I can't check that in weasyprint, but you can try:

```css
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
   width: 45%;
}
.rowTable table {
   display: inline-table;
}
:not(.rowTable) table {
   margin: 0 auto;
}

th,
td {
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding: 8px;
}

th {
  background-color: #f2f2f2;
}

.first-column {
  background-color: rgb(187, 185, 185);
}
```

```html
<div class="mainWrapper">
  <div class="rowTable">
    <table style="margin-right: 20px;">
      <tr>
        <td class="first-column">table 111 Header 1</td>
        <td>Header 2</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="first-column">Row 1, Cell 1</td>
        <td>Row 1, Cell 2</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="first-column">Row 2, Cell 1</td>
        <td>Row 2, Cell 2</td>
      </tr>
    </table>
    <table>
      <tr>
        <td class="first-column">table 222 Header 1</td>
        <td>Header 2</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="first-column">Row 1, Cell 1</td>
        <td>Row 1, Cell 2</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="first-column">Row 2, Cell 1</td>
        <td>Row 2, Cell 2</td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </div>
  <div>
    <p> some paragraph </p>
    <div>
      <div>
        <table style="margin-bottom:20px;">
          <tr>
            <th>table 333 Header 1</th>
            <th>Header 2</th>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Row 1, Cell 1</td>
            <td>Row 1, Cell 2</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Row 2, Cell 1</td>
            <td>Row 2, Cell 2</td>
          </tr>
        </table>
        <table>
          <tr>
            <th>table 444 Header 1</th>
            <th>Header 2</th>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Row 1, Cell 1</td>
            <td>Row 1, Cell 2</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Row 2, Cell 1</td>
            <td>Row 2, Cell 2</td>
          </tr>
        </table>
      </div>

    </div>
```

Comment: Only Table 1 and Table 2 should be side by side, the Table 3 and Table 4 should be one under the other. Is it possible to modify it in your answer? And is it possible to avoid using flex in `.mainWrapper` as well?

Comment: I edited my snippet, deleted flex in general and applied inline-table only to the tables in `.row-table`. For the other two I added `margin: 0 auto`to center them, but you can erase that if you want them left-aligned.